# Width in css is overriding my justify-items

Tags: html, css

My grids were aligning in the middle perfectly fine till I added a max width to my grids. Now my grid boxes align directly to the left of the webpage. Here is my code:

```
    .nested {
          width: 450px;
          display: grid;
          grid-template-columns: 1fr;
          justify-items: center;
        }
```

here is a code pen with the code: https://codepen.io/pen/?editors=1010
How come this is happening?

Comment: it would be helpful if you could provide a reproducible demo of the issue, with some HTML included.  this can be done via either adding a `snippet` to the question or linking to a service such as JSFiddle or Codepen.

Comment: @user1063287 I added a codepen to the post. I hope that helps. Thanks.

Comment: it looks like that codepen link is not working.  you need an account there to save the codepen and link to it (and be able to reference it in the future).  it is free.  as mentioned, if you don't want to do that, you can also add a snippet to your question (which includes HTML, CSS etc).  you can learn how to do that here:  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356679

Answer (score 0):

For setting the max-width of each grid column, use the `fit-content` property.

"The fit-content function accepts one param, the maximum value. A grid column/row with this property set will still take up as little space as necessary, according to its content, but no more than the maximum value."

[Reference](https://elad.medium.com/becoming-a-css-grid-ninja-f4c6db018cc1)

```css
.nested {
          width: 450px;
          display: grid;
          grid-template-columns: fit-content(450px);
          justify-items: center;
        }
```